# Cannot create Dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I want to create a Dataframe in PySpark with the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

temp = Row("DESC", "ID")
temp1 = temp('Description1323', 123)

print temp1

schema = StructType([StructField("DESC", StringType(), False),
                     StructField("ID", IntegerType(), False)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(temp1, schema)
```

But i am receiving the following error:

> TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'Description1323' in type
>   type 'str'

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a `Row` where you should be passing a list of `Row`s. Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

temp = Row("DESC", "ID")
temp1 = temp('Description1323', 123)

print temp1

schema = StructType([StructField("DESC", StringType(), False),
                     StructField("ID", IntegerType(), False)])

df = spark.createDataFrame([temp1], schema)

df.show()
```

And the result:

```
+---------------+---+
|           DESC| ID|
+---------------+---+
|Description1323|123|
+---------------+---+
```